# Jsch 0.1.54 session.connect() throws com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read

Tags: session, ssh

I use he below code to connect to the ssh server.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "ip", port);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("kex", "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1");
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setPassword("password");
session.connect(5000); // Exception raises here
```

Exception is shown as below.

```
     com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
```

Since I do not get the logs(because of application limitation), I captured the session via WireShark and it is showing a reset request is send by the ssh server during key exchange.
Attaching the screen shot of the same.

[wireshark session image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw0ht.png)

in the above image, xx.xx.xx.29 is my machine and xx.xx.xx.51 is the ssh server ip

I am not finding any solution in other threads here. Please help me.

Comment: any Solution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check kex online for many of the answers.
`Session. SetConfig (kex ", "" diffie-hellman group1 -- sha1");`